# NSUserDefaults messing with SegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a simple expense tracker app that has at the top a Segmented control to change currency (Romanian currency, Euro and $ in this order). In my list manager I have methods that convert from one to another and in the view controller, based on the Segmented control, I call them accordingly.

My problem is the following: When the app starts, the selected currency is always the first - Ro currency. If I add some elements and then I quit the app with another currency selected, I guess NSUserDefaults synchronizes with those values. When I open the app again, Ro currency is again selected, but with the $/euro values. (Say I add 410 ron, which converted is ~$100. I select $ and kill the app from multitasking. When I open it up again, it show 100 ron, instead of 410). If a currency is selected and add a certain amount, it performs ok (if $ is selected and I add 100, when I switch the control to ron it displays 410). I guess I have to change something with the synchronization, but I can't figure out where and how.

EDIT2: Some code  (sorry)

//This is the expenses class
import UIKit

class Expense: NSObject, NSCoding {

```
//MARK: Properties

var title:String?
var amount:Double?

init(title:String,amount:Double){
    self.title = title
    self.amount = amount
}

override init(){
    super.init()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    if let titleDecoded = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("title") as? String{
        title = titleDecoded
    }
    if let amountDecoded = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("amount") as? Double{
        amount = amountDecoded
    }

}

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    if let titleEncoded = title {
        aCoder.encodeObject(titleEncoded, forKey:"title")
    }
    if let amountEncoded = amount {
        aCoder.encodeObject(amountEncoded, forKey:"amount")
    }
}
```

}

//The NSUserDefaultsManager 
import UIKit

class NSUserDefaultsManager: NSObject {
    static let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

```
class func synchronize(){
    let myData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(ExpenseManager.expenses)

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myData, forKey: "expensearray")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}

class func initializeDefaults(){
    if let expensesRaw = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dataForKey("expensearray"){
        if let expenses = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(expensesRaw) as? [Expense]{
            ExpenseManager.expenses = expenses
        }
    }
}
```

}

I call the initializeDefaults in the tableview manager in view did load, the synchronize in view did appear and in the App Delegate module, sync in applicationWillTerminate.

ANSWER

I found a solution - it was quite obvious. I found it in a Google Books - iOS 9 Programming Fundamentals by Matt Neuburg. 
In the segmented control action I added the following

let c = self.currencySelector.selectedSegmentIndex
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(c, forKey: "selectedcurrency")

while in viewDidLoad I added

let c = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("selectedcurrency") as! Int
        currencySelector.selectedSegmentIndex = c

Comment: For this kind of question, you might need to show some code... e.g. show how NSUserDefaults is read and how the values (or at least some of them) are populated.

Comment: Don't post images, post code. Nobody who's willing to help is willing to retype the code for testing it in a Playground.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I don't have enough reputation to comment. But could you show the code, and Im guessing you're not synchronizing something or just not pulling it up in ViewDidLoad, etc.